# Proof of differentiability for F-related vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, vector-fields

I have two differentiable manifolds, $M$ and $N$, and a differential map $f : M \mapsto N$ which is a diffeomorphism. For $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ I want to show a map $f_*X : N \mapsto TN$ is differentiable. The map is given by

$f_*X(q) = (df)_{f^{-1}(p)}(X(f^{-1}(p))$.

Because the map is a diffeomorphism I believe I can claim that $X$ and $f_*X$ are f-related. It follows that I can write, $f_*(X)(h) = X(h \circ f)f^{-1}$ where $h \in C^{\infty}(N)$.

Comment: In coordinates, your map is clearly smooth since it is a smooth matrix applied to a smooth vector.

Comment: Yes, sorry my question was unclear, I just edited.

Comment: I answered the first part of your question. For the second part, please try to define your notations so to make the question clear.

Comment: $\phi$ is the map $\phi : M \mapsto T_{r,s}(M)$ such that $\phi(\alpha_1,...\alpha_r,...Y_1,....Y_s) : M \mapsto R$

Comment: Your second question should follow easily from your definitions of the various $*$.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, $x \in X$, which is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $Df:TM\rightarrow TN$ is the derivative of $f$, that is $Df(p, v):= \big(Df(p)\big)(v)$ (or $df_p(v)$ in your notation) where $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$. First show that $Df$ is smooth when written in a chart (for this, pay attention to how you define the atlas on the tangent bundle). Then just note that $f_*X$ is the composition $Df \circ X \circ f^{-1}$ of smooth functions.